# Radio button problem with Javascript and Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, radio-button, dom-events

I am  new to Javascript so I should use some help, I am creating new site via Wordpress and I have a little problem. In forms I have radio button which questions persons if they want pauses (site is for uber drivers), so if you check yes then there should appear new input with question for exact address where pause should be. I've made Javascript code which does that, but problem is that code is working well on a PC but it doesn't seem to be working on mobile's.

Plugins used on site: **NinjaForms** and **Elementor**.

Here is also direct link to the form so you can check by yourself. http://adwientaxi.com/order/

```
window.onload=function(){

document.getElementById("nf-field-13-0").addEventListener("click", function(){

document.getElementById('nf-field-14-wrap').style.display = 'block';

});

document.getElementById("nf-field-13-1").addEventListener("click", function(){

document.getElementById('nf-field-14-wrap').style.display = 'none';

});

}
```